# Dell Latitude without TPM - can I create multiple USB flash drives for BitLocker startup-key storage?

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker, dell-latitude

We have a user that needs a new laptop (OS is Win10 Pro) and the only one available in the remote office does not have a TPM. However, our new security protocols dictate that BitLocker must be used on all laptops.

I set the laptop up with a [Sandisk single small form-factor USB flash drive](https://www.sandisk.com/home/usb-flash/ultra-fit-usb) to store the startup keys...but **I need a backup in case that flash drive fails**, or he takes it out (he's been instructed not to, but still) and loses it, etc. Obviously the laptop won't boot if this drive is lost, so basically I'm looking for a way to prevent the flash drive from being a SPoF.

Can I simply copy the flash drive?

Comment: Yes, Of course you can duplicate the disk.

Comment: Ok, thanks @Ramhound. When I look at in in Explorer I don't see anything, but I will check hidden files, or perhaps just image-copy solution...

Comment: Apparently it's a .BEK file that I need to copy. That, plus matching the format (FAT32) and copied flash drives should work for the startup key, per: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/64b9cc66-5fe4-446d-bc88-baae7b6a3a9a/bitlocker-usb-key-create-a-duplicate?forum=w7itprosecurity

Answer (score 0):

Right-clicking the BitLocker-protected drive (C:\ in this case) and selecting **Manage BitLocker > Copy Startup Keys** was all that was needed here.